# java tips (converting string to array)

Tags: java, arrays, string, converters

there. I faced a bit trouble with java programming

**Could someone give me a hint which of the method use in order to

```
string= "23578893762467290465" convert to array y= [2,3,5,7]....??**
```

I mean, that for example y[0]=2, y[1]=3, y[2]=5....

Thanks in advance

Comment: `string.toCharArray();`

Comment: Seems you want to convert to integer array...yes?

Answer (score 2):

```
String.toCharArray()
```

From the official [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray%28%29):

> It returns a newly allocated character array whose length is the
>   length of this string and whose contents are initialized to contain
>   the character sequence represented by this string.

Answer (score 2):

Convert String to an integer array.

```
String string= "23578893762467290465";
int[] intArray = new int[string.length()];
for(int i = 0; i<string.length(); i++){
    intArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(string.charAt(i)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class StringToInt{
public int[] convert(String arg){
    char[] characters = arg.toCharArray();
    int[] integers = new int[arg.length()];

    for ( int i = 0; i < characters.length; i++ ) 
        integers[i] = Character.getNumericValue(characters[i]);  

    return integers;
}

private void prettyPrint(int[] result){
    System.out.print("array: ");
    for(int i : result){
        System.out.print(i+" ");
    }
}

public static void main(String[]args){
    StringToInt converter = new StringToInt();
    int[] result = converter.convert(args.length > 0?args[0]: "23578893762467290465" );
    converter.prettyPrint(result);
}
}
```

ok, people beat me to it. But this'll work.

in essence:

- Convert to char-array.
- call *Character.getNumericValue()* for each character.

Answer (score 0):

Another way may be:

```
int[] arr = new int[string.length()];

for(int i = 0; i<string.length(); i++){
    arr[i] = Character.getNumericValue(string.charAt(i));
    System.out.println(arr[i] + "  ") ;
}
```